# Excel duplicate data multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So usually I know what I'm trying to do and can google it and figure it out. But this, I don't even know what it's called that I'm trying to do. I have two sheets in excel (or tables in Access, whichever is easiest for you). Table A has 315 numbers and Table 2 has 146 people. I need to merge the two tables so that I have two columns. One column with each account and the other with each person. So I'll basically end up with about 46,000 rows. So:

Table 1:

number
1
2
3
4

Table 2:

person

A

B

C

D

Intended result:

Table 3:

person          number

A  |  1

A  |  2

A  |  3

A  |  4

B  |  1

B  |  2

B  |  3

B  |  4

C  |  1

C  |  2

C  |  3

C  |  4

And so on. If I was doing PHP with mysqli, I'd just output a for loop but I only have access/excel available to me here and I don't know enough VBA to make my own macro (if I knew what I was trying to do, here is where I'd google it). So, I appreciate any willingness to help even though I'm not even providing code that I've tried simply because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you have Excel 2016 or Excel 2013 with Power Query? If not, VBA is probably your best bet.

Comment: Neither. 2010. I'm assuming VBA is going to be my best option, some sort of macro, I just don't know what I'm googling for. Baha.

Comment: just a note that you would Google for: "cross join" and (Excel or Access)

Comment: And that's what I didn't know. Didn't know what term to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with a loop.

Here's a basic example of what it would look like reading these in as ranges.

```
Sub Looping()
Dim n As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1:A4")
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B4")

n = 0
For Each i In rng1
    For Each j In rng2
        n = n + 1
        Cells(n, "D").Value = i.Value & j.Value
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Where your `1,2,3,4` is in `A1:A4`, your `A,B,C,D` is in `B1:B4`, and the output goes to `D1:D16`.

As @Mat'sMug said though, it is probably better to use tables than to have to define your exact ranges.

Comment: I'm giving you the vote because you gave me the code. Had to adjust it a little (needed the i value and j value in separate columns, but that was an easy adjustment). I appreciate your help in helping the fledgling programmer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Access, the query would be

```
SELECT Table2.person, Table1.number INTO Table3
FROM Table1, Table2;
```

Comment: Ha! Didn't realize [tag:access] was in the equation - that's definitely the ideal solution: a simple cross join straight at the source =)

Comment: I'm ashamed that I didn't think of that. Doh.

Comment: @Aaron - I'm even more amazed that I **did** think of it!

Answer (score 1):

Format these lists as tables, so the VBA code can use `ListObject` objects; you can take their `Range` to literally dump them into `Variant()` arrays, and then you just set up your nested loops; you'll want to switch off `Application.ScreenUpdating`, because you're going to iterate your "AccountList" while iterating your "PersonList", and the inner loop's body will be writing to the target `Worksheet`; and then you can turn the result into a `ListObject` before switching `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on. Or, let Excel repaint itself, but display a %completion status in the `Application.Statusbar` so the user knows the macro is working... but showing status and refreshing the screen will take longer than if you don't.

Comment: So you're saying have VBA pull both tables into arrays and then continuously loop/dump the array? (Once again, if this was PHP, I can completely picture what you're saying). Are you willing to give me a code snippet start? (I knew I shouldn't have skipped VB class...)

Comment: Mind you, the data is fixed (I know all the data), I'm just looking for the fastest way for me to combine and duplicate instead of me copying and pasting 146 items 315 times.

Comment: @Aaron straight-up SQL is the easiest, simplest, fastest way to do this - I only hadn't realized you had the data in MS-Access. [YowE3K has your best solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39584776/1188513) :)

Comment: No prob. I appreciate your willingness. I'm ashamed I didn't think about the join. haha.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy.

What you want to do is iterate item by item of the first column and for every iteration it will iterate the second column.

Something like this in Excel VBA:

```
I = 1
III = 1
Do While Not Range("A" & I) = ""
       II = 1
       Do While Not Range("B" & II) = ""

           /Your Code Goes Here
           /For example:
           Range("C" & III) = Range("A" & I)
           Range("D" & III) = Range("B" & II)
           III = III + 1

           II = II + 1
       Loop
   I = I + 1
Loop
```

Cheers! You'll get there.